# Problems regarding the network manager with Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit and our school uses a network with `WPA2 Enterprise security` and `PEAP` authentication without a certificate. The inner authentication method used is `MSCHAPv2`. In order not to be bugged by the continuous prompt of the OS for the network password at the login screen(this bug was documented on launchpad) I unticked the box `All users may connect to this network`.

However, after saving these settings I noticed that when I locked the computer by closing the lid(suspending it) the PC disconnected from the Wi-Fi network and did not reconnect without manual intervention.

How can I change this behavior and is there another work around for the problem of getting prompted for the network password constantly at the login screen apart from unticking the `All users may connect ...` tick box? Any help and suggestions are appreciated. I post the screenshots of the settings in the network-manager below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]